# How do I show Bootstrap alert in php?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created and login page using bootstrap. I have a php code that checks and authenticate the username and password. I want to use bootstrap alert to show an incorrect username and password message on top of the login input fields. With what I have done currently, the alert message shows as soon as I run the php page. I want the alert message to show on top of the login input field only after the login button has been click. 
Below is the code:

```
<body>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
<?php
require 'include/global.php';
require_once 'util/util.php'; 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=md5($_POST['password']);
}

$query="select * from user where username ='$username' and password='$password'";

$result=mysql_query($query);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($count==1 && isStatus($row)==1){
// store session data
$_SESSION['loggedin']=$_POST['username'];

header("Location:welcome.php");
}else {
echo"<div id='myAlert' class='alert alert-danger'>
        <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</a>
        <strong>Warning!</strong>&nbsp;Username or Password Incorrect!&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='index.php'>GO TO HOME</a><br>
    </div>";

require 'include/footer.php';
}
 function isStatus($row) 
    {
        if (!empty($row))
         {
            foreach($row as $key=>$value )
            {   
                if ( $key=="status" && $value==1) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: IS the issue that your `else` statement is called on first load? If so it's because you may need to check that a form was submitted eg  `}elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections!  I'd fix that before you implement Bootstrap alerts! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the form was submitted. You can use `if (!empty($_POST))` to check if the form was submitted or not. Hope it helps.